# Android Firebase - Login to multiple Realtime DB on different projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a main Firebase Relatime Database with users that login and access data.
I also have a few other databases that I want them to be able to login to as well.

So the idea is that they login to "Database A" with email and password, and then in the menu there is an option to view the reports from another "Database B" and "Database C".

When I try to switch databases, I get `Permission Denied`. The exact error is:

`Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`

I am trying to get a list of users from the `/users` path.

Now the problem is, while the user exists on all databases with the same email and password, I presume this doesn't matter to firebase because the `UID` is different. So how can I seemlessly login to multiple projects with the same user, or is this possible?

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void switchDatabase(AvailableDatabase selectedDatabase) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Switching DB: Name: %s, ID: %s, URL: %s", selectedDatabase.getName(), selectedDatabase.getApplicationId(), selectedDatabase.getUrl()));

    if (selectedDatabase.getApplicationId() == null || selectedDatabase.getUrl() == null) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Invalid DB Connection for " + selectedDatabase.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId(selectedDatabase.getApplicationId())
            .setApiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key)) // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl(selectedDatabase.getUrl()) // Required for Realtime DB.
            .build();

    //Get secondary DB.
    // First try get by name, in case it already exists.
    // If that fails, create it
    FirebaseApp app;
    try {
        app = FirebaseApp.getInstance(selectedDatabase.getName());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firebase DB " + selectedDatabase.getName() + " doesn't exist. Creating...");
        app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, selectedDatabase.getName());
    }


    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    secondaryDatabase.getReference().child(FB_USER).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "DB request cancelled:getUsers::" + databaseError.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the firebase rules for /users:

```
"users" : {
    ".read" : "auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 1' || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 2'|| root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 3' || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 4')", 
    ".write" : "auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 1' || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 2'|| root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 3' || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('profile').child('access_level').val() === 'Level 4')"
 },
```

As you can see, they're tied to the `auth.uid`. If I'm coming from another project, the user email will be the same but the auto-generated UID won't be, so the permissions fail since the `auth.uid` doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only resource online about this topic. However, it's incomplete for what I need, ie navigating the unique UIDs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly:

```
// Retrieve other app.
FirebaseApp otherApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("otherApp");
// Get the database for the other app.
FirebaseDatabase otherDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(otherApp);
```

Read more here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

> For Android apps using Firebase, there is a central FirebaseApp object
>   that manages the configuration for all the Firebase APIs. This is
>   initialized automatically by a content provider when your app is
>   launched, and you typically never need to interact with it. However,
>   when you want to access multiple projects from a single app, you'll
>   need a distinct FirebaseApp to reference each one individually. It's
>   up to you to initialize the instances other than the default that
>   Firebase creates for you. For example, to connect to the default
>   Firebase Database instance, we implicitly use the default Firebase
>   app:
>
> ```
> FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
> ```
>
> To connect to another Firebase Realtime Database from another project,
>   you first need to initialize a FirebaseApp instance for that other
>   Firebase project, and give it an identifier - in this case
>   "secondary":
>
> ```
> FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
>        .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Required for Analytics.
>        .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Required for Auth.
>        .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/")
> // Required for RTDB.
>        .build();
> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary"); Then, you can access the database using the same client
> ```
>
> APIs, but this time specifying which project you want to access by
>   passing the relevant FirebaseApp to FirebaseDatabase.getInstance():
>
> ```
> // Retrieve my other app.
> FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
> // Get the database for the other app.
> FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
> ```

Comment: Yes, that is the URL I was using to get the initial code. I'm having issues with bringing over the `UID` of the user though. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by bringing over cause finding the logged in user uid is pretty simple

Comment: Imagine you create a User in your database. There's a unique ID that is generated. Now imagine creating that same user in the 2nd DB. Another unique ID will be created. These obviously don't match, so when I request a path from DB2, eg /users/ <UID>/profile/email, then it won't find it as the `UID` is different.

Comment: The uid from firebase authentication remains the same for the user given that the auth provider is same.

Comment: I'm looking at my 2 DBs side by side, and the users have different UIDs. I don't understand how they would be the same since they're just JSON fields that are created at 2 different times for arbitrary objects. I'm not using SSO form Google/Facebook.